# Is there any way to use libVLC in flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, libvlc

I wanted to build a video player for android using flutter & libVLC, to play videos stored on device.
How can I implement it?

I am pretty new to flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
[flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player) plugin

and set url to `file://${file.path}`

You can get file path using file picker

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player)

First add it:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_vlc_player: ^3.0.3
```

Then use it like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

class ExampleVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleVideoState createState() => _ExampleVideoState();
}

class _ExampleVideoState extends State<ExampleVideo> {
  final String urlToStreamVideo = 'http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4';
  final VlcPlayerController controller = new VlcPlayerController(
      // Start playing as soon as the video is loaded.
      onInit: (){
          controller.play();
      }  
  );
  final int playerWidth = 640;
  final int playerHeight = 360;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
            height: playerHeight,
            width: playerWidth,
            child: new VlcPlayer(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                url: urlToStreamVideo,
                controller: controller,
                placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a dumb doubt How can I implement this package for videos stored in the device?

Comment: @ShubhamPatel in that case follow [this tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video#1-add-the-video_player-dependency). this one can play videos online and on device.

Comment: Yes I tried that one too but it stutter for a split second when I go forward 10 seconds in a video, maybe I am implementing it wrong(I am using seek to) how do you suggest I should implement this functionality?

Comment: @ShubhamPatel i actually dont have much experience about it. but since its from Flutter developers you may find your answer in their github page

Comment: Great Thanks I will ask on github, where should I ask? can you share a link

Comment: @ShubhamPatel yes. check [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+video+player)